# How to binarize image, Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to binarize image so I have twice as many white pixels as black pixels.
Someone gave me answer:

```
binarized = im2bw(image, 0.28)
```

and I'm not sure how do this person know that level 0.28 gives twice as many white as black?
In this code, I had to use gamma correction, use imhist, binarize. My code:

```
   close all;
    clear all;
   clc;



  img = imread('cameraman.tif');
  img = double(img)/255;
   coeff = 0.6;
  gamma = img.^coeff;
               figure;
    subplot(121); imshow(img); title('Oryginalny');
   subplot(122); imshow(gamma); title('Po korekcji gamma');

    equalized = histeq(gamma,32);

    figure;
     subplot(221); imshow(gamma); title('Po korekcji gamma');
      subplot(222); imshow(equalized); title('Wyrównany');
   subplot(223); imhist(gamma); title('Po korekcji gamma');
     subplot(224); imhist(equalized);  title('Wyrównany');

   SE = strel('disk', 3);
    eroded = imerode(equalized,SE);
    opening = imdilate(eroded,SE);

     figure;
   subplot(121); imshow(equalized); title('Wyrównany');
   subplot(122); imshow(opening); title('Otwarcie');

      binarized = im2bw(opening, 0.28);
  figure;
   imshow(binarized); title('Po binaryzacji');

    w = binarized == 1;
          b = binarized == 0;
      biale = sum(w(:));
       czarne = sum(b(:));
```

Comment: You can't just use a hard-coded value here - you have to first calculate the threshold based on a luminance histogram of the image and then use that value as a threshold for `im2bw`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how to do it? I am a newbie.

Comment: Start by reading the MATLAB manual entry for [imhist](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/imhist.html)

Comment: I'm so stupid, I've already used imhist in this code. I edited my first post so you can see my code, but I don't understand connection between imhist and level in binarized

Comment: (1) use `imhist` to generate a histogram (2) scan the histogram to find the threshold where you have twice as many pixels above the threshold as below it (3) apply that threshold value with `im2bw`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm scanning histogram, I wanted to post a picture of it, but I don't have enough reputation points. I really want to understand it, but I don't really see why 0.28 level was chosen. I know that histogram respresent number of pixels of certain shade, and I don't really see how to find a point where we have twice as many as other color. Sorry for my stupidity! :D

Comment: It's just very simple math - you know how many pixels there are in the image (n = width * height) - from this you know how many black pixels you need (n / 3), so you can just iterate through the histogram accumulating bin counts until you reach this count (n / 3). The intensity at which this happens is the threshold value you need for this particular image.

Comment: Thank you, but how to finf width and height of my image? Can it be:image=imread('cameraman.tif');
[x,y]=size(image); ?

Comment: Sure - why not ? You should really try stuff before asking - you'll learn a lot faster that way.

Comment: Probably yes, but I feel really intimidated with Matlab

Comment: Reading a good book on MATLAB before you get too much further might help. Also there is no reason to feel intimidated - you can't break anything - just try things and learn.

Comment: Personally, I would sort the luminance values and use the value 1/3 up the list as the threshold for `im2bw`, but I completely agree with @PaulR that you should just try stuff. Matlab is a great tool for playing around in.

Comment: Sorting would work too, but histogramming is O(n) whereas sorting is typically O(n log n) - it probably makes little difference in this case though, so whatever is simplest to implement is probably best.